# manually change dataset metadata_modified in CKAN

Tags: python-2.7, dataset, ckan

I would set up the metadata_modified field for datasets to a certain date, I wrote a function that replace package_update

```py
def my_custom_function(pk_id):

    date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
    pkg = package_show({'model': ckan.model}, {'id': pk_id})
    last_date = None
    for rr in pkg.get('resources'):
        curr_date = rr.get('metadata_last_modified') or rr.get('last_modified') or rr.get('created')
        curr_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(curr_date, date_format)
        if last_date is None or last_date < curr_date:
            last_date = curr_date

    for kk in ['last_modified', 'metadata_last_modified', 'metadata_modified']:
        pkg[kk] = last_date

    print package_update({'model': ckan.model, 'user': c.user}, pkg)
```

this function is correctly triggered but it doesn't change the field because in ckan/logic/action/update.py

```py
model.Session.query(model.Package).filter_by(id=pkg.id).update(
    {"metadata_modified": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
```

the field is hard coded to utcnow, so I added a few lines for changing my field manually.

```py
ckan.model.Session.query(ckan.model.Package).filter_by(id=pk_id).update(
    {"metadata_modified": my_custom_date}
)
ckan.model.Session.flush()
```

This approach doesn't work too, the date is always set to utcnow.

How ckan manage database sessions? How could I change that field manually without change the core files?

Comment: Can you explain why calculating it this way gives a better result that just recording the current date on package_update? It might be better to simply improve ckan here.

Comment: because resources are update in a automated way, there is a bigger system behind this installation of ckan. In this scenario I need to pick a date from resources and use it as my modified time. This is a project specification.

Comment: If you update the resources on CKAN using package_update or resource_update, then metadata_modified is set at that time. Isn't that what you do and want?